# Golang check if a data is time.Time

Tags: go, time, types

In a `if` condition I'm trying to know if my data's type is `time.Time`.

What is the best way to get the `res.Datas[i]`'s data type and check it in a `if` loop ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming type of `res.Datas[i]` is not a concrete type but an interface type (e.g. `interface{}`), simply use a [type assertion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) for this:

```
if t, ok := res.Datas[i].(time.Time); ok {
    // it is of type time.Time
    // t is of type time.Time, you can use it so
} else {
    // not of type time.Time, or it is nil
}
```

If you don't need the `time.Time` value, you just want to tell if the interface value wraps a `time.Time`:

```
if _, ok := res.Datas[i].(time.Time); ok {
    // it is of type time.Time
} else {
    // not of type time.Time, or it is nil
}
```

Also note that the types `time.Time` and `*time.Time` are different. If a pointer to `time.Time` is wrapped, you need to check that as a different type.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this clear explanation ! It actually works :)